# TCL Database connection

Tags: database, tcl

Here I am very new in TCL. Now I want to **Database connectivity in TCL**. Please tell me all the steps, how can I connect to Database and perform the CRUD (Insert, update, delete, create) operation and also tell me the basic requirement of database connection. Here I am using MySQL 5.0 database. So please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use [TDBC](http://wiki.tcl.tk/20343) with the `tdbc::mysql` driver. But if that's not an option (e.g., because you're on older Tcl) then [mysqltcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/6051) is recommended too.

Comment: Here i am using tcl 8.5. So can u give me some example for database connectivity. Please........

Comment: package require tdbc::odbc
I am not getting about above code. So how can i overcome with the problem.

Comment: The error is :
cann't find package mysqltcl while executing "Package require mysqltcl"
(procedure "dd" line 3)
invoked from within "dd"
( file "DemotoConnect.txt" line 11)

Comment: so please tell me mysqltcl, i should personally download and install on my linux PC or do something other.......please ??? Now here i am in dilemma , Please help me

Comment: @galvin: Whose distribution of Tcl are you using?

Comment: sorry, I mention above that i am using tcl 8.5. it is wrong. So here i am correcting myself now i am using tcl version 8.4.13. But how can i get the version, here i type the command info patchlevel, then i got the exact version. But i am unable to give u r question answer because here i am using linux 5.0, and i am unable to find out the exact distribution. As per my knowledge if Linux is installed in any machine so by default tcl is also installed. So please tell me how to find out tcl distribution.